# Prism modules : reference assembly once

Tags: forms, xamarin, module, prism

EDIT : got it shorter.

We created three modules following the prism doc and our requirements.

We did a horizontal slices with modules.

1. **SharedServices**
2. **BusinessLogic**
3. **UserInterface**

In the UserInterface we are using Syncfusion components and other packages, and It would be great to put everything in the **UserInterface** module but how can we reference nuget assemblies from that module in the shell (to apply theming for example) to avoid having references in each modules & the shell ?

Should we add nugetpackage to each module and the shell (is it bad... ?) or is it possible to have one module which defines base class referencing external assemblies for example and that would be themable (with ResourceDictionary) & usable in the whole solution (shell & other modules) .

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very broad question, it might well be closed, but I try to give you a few guiding thoughts:

Generally, you either slice horizontally (as you did, UI-module with all the views plus logic-module with all the services) or vertically (as your Product-module suggests: views, view models, services for the product in one module, those for the user in another).

You can do both, but then you should "slice through", so one module for product-ui, one for user-ui, one for product-services, one for user-services... you get the idea. That means a lot of modules, though.

Also, when creating your modules, have an idea of what you want to achieve. Modules can encapsulate components to be reused in another app. Or they can encapsulate exchangeable components, so you could create a car-sharing app today and tomorrow swap out the car-module for a bike-module and have a bike-sharing app. Or they can be used to enforce segregation of code based on risk analysis in a regulated environment. What I'm trying to convey: don't create modules just to have modules, make each module have a defined purpose.

Also, define the interfaces for the modules. I don't like modules to reference each other, as it effectively destroys all segregation that would otherwise be there. Create seperate non-module assemblies that only contain public interfaces. Then make your modules contain the implementations as internal types. In an ideal world, no module assembly contains a public type. The interface-assemblies can be either per module or per consumer or per link between modules (those checked boxes in your N2-chart, you have one, don't you?).

You want to keep the number of modules reasonable, as well as the dependencies between them (not as in "assembly references" but through interface-assembly).

> how can we reference nuget assemblies from that module in the shell (to apply theming for example) to avoid having references in each modules & the shell ?

You should separate the "interface" part (e.g. base classes or DTOs, not part of the module) and the actual services part (that's the module). Example: unity has a nuget package for the interfaces ([Unity.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Abstractions)) and one that contains the container implementation ([Unity.Container](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Container)). There's nothing wrong with everyone referencing the interface, basically, that's saying "I want to use that interface".

Comment: Thanks for this useful answer for conception. You are right its too broad, edited

Comment: "Then make your modules contain the implementations as internal types" . I'm a bit lost, can you explain more if you can ? Thanks !

Comment: You have an assembly containing `public interface ISomething` and your module contains `internal class DatabaseSomething : ISomething` and registers it with the container. This way other modules can get `ISomething` as dependency although they nothing about `DatabaseSomething`.

Comment: That means all modules must reference that external assembly that contains those public interfaces, right ?

Comment: Sorry for this lot of questions : "you should separate the "interface" part (e.g. base classes or DTOs, not part of the module) and the actual services part (that's the module)". I do see what you mean but can't visualize what should be done. Having classes that extends these nuget components in an external assembly that is not a module too ?

Comment: Nuget packages are just one option for deployment - you can have a nuget package for the interfaces and one for the module.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your time @Haukinger !